# RequiredFieldValidator not firing when ControlToValidate visiblity is changed

Tags: .net, asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

When I change ddl.Visible=true(it gets changed on partial postback/updatepanel from another form element event)the RequiredFieldValidator will not fire?

NOTE: This is not a question on how to use the RequiredFieldValidator in a normal circumstance.  My form has cascading dropdowns that are all dynamically built with their visibility toggled on and off.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" Visible="false" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server">                                                               
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="ddl" 
ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [`InitialValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.initialvalue.aspx) property on your `RequiredFieldValidator` so that it knows when the value of the `DropDownList` has changed.  For example, on a dropdown with these values:

> - `Please Select`
> - `Dog`
> - `Cat`
> - `Bird`

You would add this attribute

```
InitialValue="Please Select"
```

to your `RequiredFieldValidator`.

Without knowing if the value has changed it is impossible for the validator to know whether or not the user has satisfied its requirement.

Comment: InitalValue has a default of String.Empty which is what my first ListItem is.  The validators work fine as long as I don't toggle visibility.

Comment: Can you post all relevant code please?  Your question does not show a value set for InitialValue.

Comment: Andrew you are correct, digging deeper(too much dynamic making my head spin) I found that my default ListItem's value was 0 not String.Empty.  I went ahead and set my InitalValue to be explicit though.  Thanks

Comment: why does the validator need to know that a value has changed in order to determine if that value is e.g. null or not?

Comment: InitialValue is not needed for a required field validator, unless you have an 'empty' value of something other than string.empty.  The real issue is around partial postbacks and the validation framework.